# systemctl check service status with reasonable semantics?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I'm trying to write code which programmatically check service status, but is also robust to typos in service names. In my opinion a reasonable program to use would have the following behavior and semantics:

- it takes a unit name as an argument
- if that unit is found, it prints out the service status and exits with status 0 (eg active,inactive,etc...)
- if that unit is *not* found/loaded, it prints out an error and exits with a non-zero status

Notably these do not meet this requirement:

- `systemctl is-active servicename` (exits with non-zero return status if the unit is not active, identical behavior if servicename is not loaded)
- `systemctl is-failed servicename` (similar behavior to above)
- `systemctl show servicename -pActiveState` (exits with status 0 if servicename is not loaded)

It seems like the closest thing is `systemctl show servicename -pLoadState -pActiveState`  but then I have to parse the LoadState string to determine if there's a typo, which seems more complex than should be required for this simple task.

Any suggestions?

Comment: perhaps your script could check for the existence of the service before asking for the status?

Comment: the semantics just set us up for failure.  If there's a typo somewhere, or a service name changes and someone forgets to change the name in a particular place everything will operate "normally" and just subtly be broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any suggestions?

Encourage the systemd people to fix the bug that is still open from 2014.

The `systemctl` manual documents an appropriate LSB version 3 exit status, known within systemd as `EXIT_PROGRAM_OR_SERVICES_STATUS_UNKNOWN`, and this exit status is *even used* by `systemctl status` for nonexistent services, distinguishing them from services that exist but that are not running.

It is not, however, used by `systemctl is-active`.

## Further reading

- van.de.bugger (2014-12-18). *[`systemctl status` exits with failure status for a service that completed successfully](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77507#c2)*.  Bug #77507.  freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2017). "[EXIT STATUS](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#Exit%20status)". `systemctl`.  systemd manual pages.